# Can a player challenge a chair umpire correction?

Tags: rules, tennis, video-review

Players are often seen challenging out calls/non-calls by the linesmen, but when the chair umpire makes a call correction, can a player still challenge the corrected call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely, I've seen that exact scenario happen many times. It usually results in the other player having to request the challenge since the call gets changed/overruled. Challenges are available for any call, whether it's a linesperson making the call or a chair umpire.

See VII. The Competition PDF [here](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/corporate/rulebook). Look at page 130 - Section VII, #7 where it says

> The original call or overrule will always stand if the electronic
>   review is unable, for whatever reason, to make a decision on that line
>   call or overrule. In this case, the player shall not have his
>   available number of challenges reduced.

specifically mentioning the linesperson call or the chair umpires overrule.